# replacing nth element in a list of integers or chars or possibly new defined data types by the user

Tags: haskell

```
replaceIthItem :: Num a => b -> [b] -> a -> [b]
replaceIthItem _ [] _ = []
replaceIthItem a (_:xs) 0 = a : xs 
replaceIthItem a (x:xs) n = x : replaceIthItem a xs (n-1)
```

as mentioned in the title the method should work for any type of lists, the above code works only for list of integers(I am using winhugs i know it is very old, but it is not the cause of the problem right?), I have seen different ways of implementation to that function by using zip or splitAt and data.seq but there are many limitations in the project and I should do it by the recursive way, what I don't understand about Haskell that it considers a as integer or num always not like prolog that can unify the variable with the user input type, so how can I overcome that problem and have the function type to be smth like that

```
replaceIthItem :: (Eq a, Num a) => t -> [t] -> a -> [t]
```

edit: if anyone could suggest a nice guide for Haskell syntax and how type of functions is determined i would be very thankful because i spent much time on prolog and cant adjust to haskell so fast

Comment: _the above code works only for list of integers_: no, it doesn't work for anything, because it lacks the `Eq a`. The correct signature is the last one. So what puzzles you?

Comment: "above code works only for list of integers" How do you know? Show us the errors.

Comment: @Enlico for some specially selected values of "correct".`Num` is sort of an arbitrary ring. Why would anyone want to allow `replaceIthItem 0 [1..] 3.5`? Indices are integral.

Comment: @Enlico I am totally new to haskell just started studying it 2 days ago, i know the correct signature but i dont know how to apply it on my function, i stil didn't get used to the syntax of Haskell

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Unrecognised character `\146' in column 15

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Equations give different arities for "replaceIthItem" that is when adding Eq a but i am not doing it right

Comment: Ideally, when you get a compilation error, it helps everybody if the author of the question copy and paste the error.

Comment: "Unrecognised character `\1...' " usually means you are using a text editor that is too smart for its own good, or that you copy and paste from some garbage text. It has nothing to do with Haskell per se, it has to do with using correct charset and encoding for your source program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `replaceIthItem :: Num a => b -> [b] -> a -> [b]` is that it can't compare with 0 because it lacks the Eq instance, as the error likely told you.

The second signature you provided, `replaceIthItem :: (Eq a, Num a) => t -> [t] -> a -> [t]`, works fine:

```
λ> :{
 > replaceIthItem :: (Eq a, Num a) => t -> [t] -> a -> [t]
 > replaceIthItem _ [] _ = []
 > replaceIthItem a (_:xs) 0 = a : xs 
 > replaceIthItem a (x:xs) n = x : replaceIthItem a xs (n-1)
 > :}
λ> replaceIthItem 5 [1,2,3] 1
[1,5,3]
```

The problem with the code above is it can still be used in a nonsensical way, like in `replaceIthItem 5 [1,2,3] 1.5`, as @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  pointed out.

If you really want to stay polymorphic on numbers you can do `replaceIthItem :: Integral a => b -> [b] -> a -> [b]`. Integral brings Eq, [see the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral).

Notice you can still give negative numbers to `Integral a => a`, which doesn't feel very sensible for the current implementation. Alternatively, you could use [Numeric.Natural](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Numeric-Natural.html), which at least throws a runtime exception for negative numbers. eg. `replaceIthItem :: t -> [t] -> Natural -> [t]`:

```
λ> replaceIthItem 5 [1,2,3] 1
[1,5,3]
λ> replaceIthItem 5 [1,2,3] 5
[1,2,3]
λ> replaceIthItem 5 [1,2,3] (-5)

<interactive>:70:28: warning: [-Woverflowed-literals]
    Literal -5 is negative but Natural only supports positive numbers
*** Exception: arithmetic underflow
```

Comment: okay i got it and i got why i was getting errors, i am such a newbie, thanks for the time you invested in answering my silly question

Comment: This might be of assistance in the future https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.